# Displaying duplicate values in sql

Tags: sql, duplicates, records

I need to find all records where two fields in one table occur more than once in a specified date range. 
I have used the below which enables me to display the duplicates but i need to specify within a period of time, whenever i try to include a date range it starts displaying all records not just the duplicates

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
SELECT  
y.ID,y.site,y.machine
  FROM calls y
    INNER JOIN (SELECT
                    site,machine, COUNT(*) AS CountOf
                    FROM calls
                    GROUP BY site,machine
                    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
                ) dt ON y.site=dt.site and y.machine=dt.machine
```

Comment: show us the code with the date range

Comment: Surely just adding the date criteria to you SELECT...GROUP BY will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to place the date range where/on condition in both sql statements (inner & outer) in order to get the exact records you are looking for.  This can be done through where statements as follows:

```
SELECT  
y.ID,y.site,y.machine
  FROM calls y
    INNER JOIN (SELECT
                    site,machine, COUNT(*) AS CountOf
                    FROM calls
                    WHERE Date BETWEEN StartOfRange AND EndOfRange
                    GROUP BY site,machine
                    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
                ) dt ON y.site=dt.site and y.machine=dt.machine
WHERE
    y.Date BETWEEN StartOfRange AND EndOfRange
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what i was missing i was only adding it to one of the sql statements!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT y.ID,
       y.site,
       y.machine
FROM   calls y
WHERE  y.date BETWEEN ... AND ...
  AND  EXISTS (SELECT x.ID
               FROM   calls x
               WHERE  x.site = y.site
                 AND  x.machine = y.machine
                 AND  x.date BETWEEN ... AND ...
                 AND  x.ID <> y.ID);
```